# Google reCaptcha doesn't show up on IE

Tags: css, asp.net, internet-explorer, recaptcha

I am using [reCAPTCHA Version 2.1.0 for .NET](https://github.com/tanveery/recaptcha-net) `NuGet Package` with `recaptcha Api Version 2`.

Assembly Registration on the `ASPX` page:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Recaptcha.Web" Namespace="Recaptcha.Web.UI.Controls" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

**My HTML:**

```
<div style="margin-top: 10px; transform: scale(0.99); transform-origin: 0;
            -ms-transform: scale(0.99); -ms-transform-origin: 0; 
            -webkit-transform: scale(0.99); -webkit-transform-origin: 0; 
     align-content: center;">
    <cc1:Recaptcha ID="recaptcha" runat="server" Theme="Clean" Width="400" />
</div>
```

The captcha [shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1d0xU.png) on `Firefox` and `Chrome`, but [doesn't show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMg3a.png) `IE`.  I have tried on IE 10 and 11 and it doesn't display in any version of IE.

**My attempts:**

- I added `-ms-transform` and `transform` CSS properties on the DIV
- I checked the solution shown on [Google Support page](https://support.google.com/recaptcha/answer/6223838?hl=en) but it is not even in my Compatibility Settings.
- I checked the solution shown on [MSDN Forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/b6c57c4e-5499-45b2-8a00-2de960a1277a/ie-will-not-display-captcha?forum=ieitprocurrentver) by enabling `Turn off Data URI support`.
- I checked a number of posts on SO

But, none of them helped me.  It would be great, if anyone could point me in the right direction.

**A note:**

It shows up captcha control in IE when I run the application through Visual Studio under localhost.  It doesn't show the control from the deployed version on IIS.  No issues with Firefox and Chrome.  The site is on `HTTPS`, if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be a group policy enforced in the company.  The group policy forces all intranet pages to be rendered in IE with

Browser Mode: IE10 Compat View
Document Mode: IE7 standards

In order to override this policy, I have added `X-UA-Compatible` in Headers.

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

*Just a note for others that I have tried adding the same in meta tag of header section, but it didn't work.*